# Showing a map in an app, better for the user

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have an iOS app written in Swift, where I use a map to show the location of some shops to the user. When a button is tapped, the map for the current shop shows up.

It is already working, but since I am  not totally satisfied, I decided to write this post to possibily get some advice for improvement.

First, here is the related code in the app.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class Shop_ViewController: UIViewController {
    ......
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ......
        let webConfig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: webConfig)
        webView.isHidden = true
        view.addSubview(webView)
    }

    ......

    @objc func showMapForShop() {
        // This function fires, when the appropriate button is tapped.

        var urlStr = "https://maps.google.com/maps"
        urlStr += "?q=\(shopObject.gPS!)"
        urlStr += "&iwloc=A&hl=\(NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0])"
        let webReq = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlStr)!)
        webView.load(webReq)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(webView)
        webView.isHidden = false
    }
```

Second, here is a screenshot of how the map display looks.

[image]

So, as mentioned above it works. But (to start with) the top and bottom part of the image (marked on the side in grey) is lost space. Indeed 99.9% of users won't care about the coordinates of the spot and would be much happier having more space to see the map. Of course the red mark on the picture should be kept to show the important location.

I have put this up together by reading the net and I also read about the  WKUIDelegate and WKNavigationDelegate protocols. But for the time being as one can see I am not making any use of them. The final question is:

**Is there a better way to do this? And get more user satisfaction?**

For information, I am using Xcode 11.3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you're *not* using a map. You're using a web site, Google Maps. So that web site is completely in charge of what is displayed.

So use a map. Instead of a web view, use a map view (MKMapView). Now you are completely in charge of the screen, where the map goes, the region it displays, the annotation (your "red mark"), what else is on the screen, and so on.

Comment: I see, you make an interesting point. I will try to use MKMapView then as you suggest. Hoping it is going to be just as simple to implement.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the google maps SDK: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro

Comment: Probably, but for the time being I am quite happy with your first suggestion.